# How to change Picker View with a button?

Tags: swift, xcode6

```
   @IBAction func nextTurn(sender: AnyObject) {
    if numberOfTurn < (playersForPicker.count-1) {
    numberOfTurn++
    }else{
        numberOfTurn = 0
    }
    titleForTwo.title = playersForPicker[numberOfTurn]
    var lostPlayer = playersForPicker[numberOfTurn]

    playersForPicker.removeAtIndex(numberOfTurn)


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return playersForPicker[row]
    }


    playersForPicker.insert(lostPlayer, atIndex: numberOfTurn)
    startButton.setTitle("Next Turn", forState: UIControlState())

}
```

This set of code changes the title of my view fine, but it doesn't change that picker view in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are attempting to do. However, the way the code is written, pickerView is never executed since there is no call to it. Suggest you at least make a call to pickerView inside the IBAction if that is appropriate. Better, make the definition of pickerView outside the IBAction and make a call to pickerView in the appropriate place depending on what you are trying to do.

It appears that what you may be trying is to use a picker as a status indicator. I can think of better ways of achieving that goal. You may want to clarify your objectives.